# Making invisible but required <input> in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

The forms I need to check use some non-`<input>` fields but I want to make them just as `required` as text fields. So should user try to submit uncompleted information, the form won't permit it and **show** the offending field. I came up with this solution:

```
    <input type="text" class="invisible-text-input" required ng-model="doc.section[0]" ng-change="resetSection();">
```

You can probably guess what `resetSection()` does. `doc.section[0]` is set by some custom means.

CSS:

```
    .invisible-text-input {
      cursor: default;
      width: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      color: transparent;
      background-color: transparent;
      height: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Now it's really hard to accidentally get into this field but form validation will place cursor there when user try to submit form with no data. And after this user can type something there, which is uncool despite `resetSection()`.
So I need a way to block user input in this input while still keeping it required. `disabled` and `readonly` will make the form ignore the input so I can't just use them.

Comment: How about `input type='hidden'` ?

Comment: Do you have custom validation ? If not, just disable the submit button when `form.$invalid` and focus problem will not be a concern.

Comment: @RayonDabre, in that case the browser will indicate missing field in upper left corner of the window.

Comment: @DianaR, that's how it was before. I need better solution.

Comment: @Moorindal Can you explain why you need hidden inputs for this and show how do you perform validation if not using the standard one?

Comment: @Moorindal, Have you tried with hidden fields ?

Comment: @DianaR, I need invisible inputs so the browser could show the user exact location of unfilled field.

Comment: @RayonDabre, I did, see the third comment in the thread.

Comment: @Moorindal, Can you provide fiddle of the same ?

Comment: @Moorindal a fiddle of plunkr would help a lot to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.